# How to add many event's participants to a single group

Tags: civievent, groups

Civi 4.5.8 - We have many Events with the same name but different dates.  For example.  "Build House A", Date March 4th 8am to 4pm.  "Build House A" March 7th 8am to 4pm.  "Build House A", Date March 8th 8am to 4pm.

We could have many of these Events for the same Build(Event Type).  Everything works fine until I try to build a list of all participants for the same Build or same Event Title.  Is there any way to group/list/report on all participants of an Event with the same Title?

Answer (score 1):

couple of options

if you go to Participants for your event eg http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/search?reset=1&force=1&status=true&event=3 then you can select all and 'add contacts to group'

or if you have the Event ID then Search Builder accepts the id for an = query on Event - ie entering 3 gets me

18 Contacts 
Event = Rain-forest Cup Youth Soccer Tournament

So your query would be 
Participant > Event > '=' > 3

in the example above.

Any help?

Comment: THANK YOU!  Yes...  the search builder with Event ID = 481 and then select "Also Include Contacts Where" and then do the same as above works.  This does allow me to add to a group.  The other method you mentioned does not allow me to add to a group.  We are on 4.5.8.

Comment: This works, however, still looking for an easier way. We have 94 events with the same name... just different days.  So I need to select 94 different events!  Ahh..  Would be nice if the Search Builder would work for Event Title Like... but is doesn't work.  When I use Like it gives me every participant for every Event in the system.   OR better yet it would be nice if I could build a smart group based on Title Like and Date Range of Event.

Comment: Search Builder using Like as the operator does not work.  Tested on the 4.7.4 demo site.

Comment: Sorry... the search builder does work on the 4.7 demo site.  I was forgetting to put the % sign in.  It does not work on our 4.5.8 site.  I guess this will force use to upgrade... ahh.. the pain of upgrading!

Comment: maybe i misunderstood - you want a group per event, or per 'common word' in the Event Title

Comment: Group per "Common Word"...  We have many events (type is Build) where we are building a house (Habitat for Humanity).  Each event name is the same (ie. "River Community Build" or "Veterans Build").  And for each event we have volunteers that sign up to help build for that day or event.  So we could have 100 different volunteers as participants with the 94 events called "River Community Build".  So I need to group all participants from all the events called "River Community Build".

Comment: so in Adv Search %river community build% can't be used - dang - seems like the new widget there could be improved to let that occur - seems a valid use to me